# How to remove a library whose initial migration is being depended on?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

So my model used to inherit from a `Message` class of `django-postman` library.

Therefore my `0001_initial` migration looks like this:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('postman', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Message',
            fields=[
                ('message_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='postman.Message')),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('deliver_at', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('content', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
            ],
            bases=('postman.message',),
        ),
    ]
```

Now I want to totally remove my own `Message` model. I can remove it normally and run `makemigrations` which creates `0004_delete_message` that looks like this:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('postman', '0001_initial'),
        ('my_app', '0003_migrate_data_to_new_model'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='Message',
        ),
    ]
```

Now the issue is that I totally want to remove `django-postman` library, including from my `INSTALLED_APPS`. This creates the issue of both of these migrations not being applicable because they both depend on `postman.0001_initial` which doesn't exist anymore.

Is there clean way of going about that deprecation while still keeping my migrations working or do I have to manually edit my `0001_initial` and run `CreateModel` for the model introduced in `postman.0001_initial`, and change `bases` of my model to point to that model I created?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to modify `0001_initial` as you suggest to conform to the state of the installed code at run time.